# How to generate tokens for my two node Cassandra cluster?

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am trying to setup two node Cassandra Cluster on windows machine. I have basically two windows machine and I was following this datastax [tutorial](http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/how-to-setup-and-monitor-a-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-windows)

Whenever I use the below command to get the token number from the above tutorial -

```
python -c "num=2; print ""\n"".join([(""token %d: %d"" %(i,(i*(2**127)/num))) for i in range(0,num)])"
```

I always get this error -

```
C:\Users\username>python -c "num=2; print ""\n"".join([(""token %d: %d"" %(i,(i*(2**127)/num))) for i
in range(0,num)])"
  File "<string>", line 1
    num=2; print "\n".join([("token %d: %d" %(i,(i*(2**127)/num))) for i in range(0,num)])
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck putting that command into an actual Python script.
Here is a similar Python script that I use (saved as newCluster.py):

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
        num=int(sys.argv[1])
else:
        num=int(raw_input("How many nodes are in your cluster? "))
for i in range(0, num):
        print 'node %d: %d' % (i, (i*(2**127)/num))
```

When I run that for two nodes, I get:

```
How many nodes are in your cluster? 2
node 0: 0
node 1: 85070591730234615865843651857942052864
```

Here is exactly how I edit and run it:

[image]

Which version of Python are you using?  I have tested this script in 2.6.7 and 2.7.3.

Also to be balanced, your initial_token values for a two node cluster simply need to have a difference of 85,070,591,730,234,615,865,843,651,857,942,052,864.  They don't necessarily have to be 0 and 85070591730234615865843651857942052864; although those two values should work just fine.

Comment: I copied the above content in a notepad file and save it as newcluster.py.. When I am running from the cmd prompt like this `C:\Users\uname\Desktop>newcluster.py`. I always get this error `File "newcluster.py", line 8
    print 'node %d: %d' % (i, (i*(2**127)/num))
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I am running `C:\Python33>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Comment: remove the extra space between % and ( on the last line. That should be more like `print 'node %d: %d' %(i, (i*(2**127)/num))`